# Edit User Information for other user

Tags: php, mysql, post, get, sql-update

Sorry I'm beginner in PHP MYSQL. 
I want to ask how this will work. May I know how to fix this or what code will I add?

**Scenario**:
We have user type *ADMIN* and *NORMAL USER*,
I created **edit.php** to edit user accounts as an *ADMIN* incase of lost password etc. but I have problem was when I click Edit button in specific table.

*See Picture Below, I logged in here as an Admin, employee.php. 
So **I choose the user testFN with the id of 22***
 [image]

The code I used here to fetch the id is here :

```
<td><a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>" >Edit</a></td>
```

When I click the **EDIT** button it will open the page **edit.php**, with this url 
[image]

So I the outcome is not equal to what I want, the information to the input boxes were from the user I'm using/logged in not from the user I chose to edit.

[image]

The code I used to **EDIT.PHP** is here:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
 { header("Location: edit.php");  }

$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);

if(isset($_GET['user'])) {

$id = $_GET['user'];

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$pass = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']));
$aFName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['aFName']);
$aLName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['aLName']);
$aMName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['aMName']);
$aContact = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['aContact']);
$aAddress = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['aAddress']);
$aGender = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['aGender']);
$utype = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['utype']);

$query3=mysql_query("UPDATE accounts SET pass='$pass', agentFName ='$aFName', agentLName = '$aLName', 
    agentMName = '$aMName', agentContact = '$aContact', agentAddress = '$aAddress', 
    agentGender = '$aGender', user_type = '$utype'  ");

if($query3) 
 {  header("Location: home.php"); }
    }//end of post sumbit
 }//end of GET
 ?>

   /** HTML IS HERE **/

 Agent ID: <input type="text" id="agentCode" name="agentCode" required="required" value="<?php echo $userRow['user_id']; ?>"  >

 First Name: <input type="text" id="agentCode" name="aFName" required="required" value="<?php echo $userRow['agentFname']; ?>"  >

 Middle Name: <input type="text" id="agentCode" name="aMName" required="required" value="<?php echo $userRow['agentMname']; ?>"  >

 Last Name: <input type="text" id="agentCode" name="aLName" required="required" value="<?php echo $userRow['agentLname']; ?>"  >
```

Comment: what's the value of `$_SESSION['user']`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- user_id  which is the id of the users

Comment: so it's a string? I didn't ask for the column name, I asked what the session array value is.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  No, it was INT (Auto-Increment).

Comment: if it's not working then check for errors, using error reporting and `mysql_error()` against your query, and/or ask David; he's given you an answer below. It's basically out of my hands now ;-) and this `dbconnect.php` is unknown.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you.

Comment: I also don't see any form tags; if that's your full code. Ask David. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33072666/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91995/discussion-between-edmhar-and-fred-ii).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where you set the value for that text input:

```
value="<?php echo $userRow['user_id']; ?>"
```

Where does `$userRow` come from?  This:

```
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
```

What query was used to fetch the data?  This:

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
```

So... you're specifically fetching the data from the logged-in session user, rather than the one specified on the query string.  Just use the query string value instead of the session value.

**Important:**

1. Using user-supplied values directly in SQL queries is called a SQL injection vulnerability.  It's a very bad thing.  You're going to want to use query parameters and prepared statements.  [This is a good place to start reading](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).
2. You're *really* going to want to check if the logged-in user is *authorized* to edit the specified user before allowing them to do so.  Any user can manually add/change query string values or POST values or basically anything that comes from the client.

Comment: I'm so sorry I'm stil beginner in PhP MySQL, regarding condition for authorized visit I know that I will have that condition.

 What I'm trying to do is, So I'm logged in as an Admin, I want to edit specific user. then instead of the users information inside the input values it's show the logged in user info.

Comment: $userRow is same as $query

Comment: @Edmhar: Right, that's because you're getting the logged-in user info from the database instead of the specified user.  Get the information for the query string user ID instead of the session user ID.  (Also, you might want to double-check that `UPDATE` statement.  Without a `WHERE` clause it's going to update *every* user record.)

Comment: Thanks, I added now WHERE user_id= 'user' , Am I right?  but still can't get any idea how to edit the specific user I want.

Comment: @Edmhar: Both for getting the information about the user and for saving that information back to the database you'll need to have a `WHERE` clause which specifies the user ID.  The user ID is what you're getting from the `$_GET[]` collection.  I don't know how else to explain it.  You have a variable with the user ID that you want, just use that variable.  (**Important:** Use it as a query parameter in a prepared statement, **do not** just add it to the string like you do now.)